# результат query ничего не нашел

Tags: postgresql

Задание.Вывести список работников, у которых средняя стоимость заказов на товары, изготовленных компанией ACI, выше, чем средняя общая стоимость заказов.

```
SELECT name, avg(amount)
FROM SalesReps 
JOIN Orders ON rep = empl_num 
GROUP BY name,mfr 
HAVING mfr = 'ACL' 
AND avg(amount) > (SELECT avg(amount) FROM Orders);
```

Orders таблица
[image: Orders таблица]

SalesReps таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
результат, который должен быть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, avg(amount)
FROM SalesReps 
JOIN Orders ON rep = empl_num 
GROUP BY name,mfr 
--- HAVING mfr = 'ACL' 
HAVING mfr = 'ACI' 
AND avg(amount) > (SELECT avg(amount) FROM Orders);
```

Comment: чем ваше решение отличается от моего query?

Comment: HAVING mfr = 'ACL'  ACL XXXXX плохо  ACI ХОРОШО описка в запросе

Comment: не заметил, спасибо